# Not able to display 404 error in prod environment

Tags: symfony

When I try to throw a simple `throw $this->NotFoundHttpException('We do not currently have a website configured at this address. Please visit our website for more information or contact our support team');`in dev environment, it works fine. But when I do the same in prod environment I get 500 server error. [image]

Any ideas?

Here are screenshots of my dev and prod log files

[image]

[image]

Note: 500 error only happens when I use `www` in the url in prod env. On using any other word eg. `nike`, this is what i get 
[image]

Here is the dev env result for the normal `www.blore.eduflats.com` url
[image]

Comment: Any messages in your log file?

Comment: i just posted them

Comment: not sure how to make sense of'em

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-errors-and-404-pages) in order to return a 404 from your controller you need to do the following:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');
```

Whereas, you have

```
throw $this->NotFoundHttpException
```

The error you are seeing is telling you that `NotFoundHttpException` does not exist. To fix your problem simply replace `NotFoundHttpException` with `createNotFoundException`

Comment: I just tried `throw $this->createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');`  same result

Comment: Apologies, I misread the part where you said it worked in development. In that case I will delete this answer. But first you should check you are running the same version of symfony in dev and production.

Comment: The answer is actually pretty close.  The createNotfoundException() method is defined in the base controller class which is why it is not in your class.  Try: throw new new NotFoundHttpException($message);  As for production vs development?  Bit of a mystery but development has extra listeners which might be preventing your listener from receiving events.

Comment: @Cerad I tried `throw new new NotFoundHttpException($message);`, still, works in dev but not in prod

Comment: Here's the prod log `
[2016-06-10 16:51:00] request.ERROR: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: Some description at /var/www/html/Eduflats/src/Eduflats/Bundle/EduflatsBundle/Services/UniversityResolver.php line 41) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException(code: 0): Some description at /var/www/html/Eduflats/src/Eduflats/Bundle/EduflatsBundle/Services/UniversityResolver.php:41)"} []`

Comment: Tell me 1 thing - Open this page in `dev` and how many Exceptions you got? Its possbile previous exceptions broken your `prod` page.

Comment: Take a deep breath, stop for a moment and think about things.  You have not posted any of your code.  I suspect you may be misinterpreting what is happening in development.  The development environment may be wrapping your errors so you only think your code is running.  Configure your development machine to run in production mode and see what happens.  I'm also guessing you may have multiple errors and that you are looking at the wrong part of your code.

Comment: @Cerad I understand ur point, but I am not supposed to share the code outside of my team.

Comment: I just updated a few details agan, may help figure out whats going on

Comment: You just got Exception in your UniversityResolver... but why HttpExcpetion can you show screen with this? Some magic happen :D now i dont understand where is problem...

Answer (score 0):

You call `Eduflas.. UniversityResolver->NotFoundHttpException();`
If you want to trhow exception like this, you should declare it.
Symfony Controller have `$this->createNotFoundException('Something Not found');`
You can throw 404 like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
//...
throw new NotFoundHttpException("Not found");
```

Use this way to be sure that Exception exist and test it.
**Anyway** clear your production and dev **cache** to be sure you use "the same code".
Last thing that come to my head - its possible you override error pages and you make something to your error.html.twig or error404.html.twig and you got different pages.

---

**EDIT**
When i enter your `http://blore.eduflats.com/` i got

"array(29) { ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(18) "blore.eduflats.com" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> s..."

Anyway your dev env. got error too so how it can work on prod env...
If you throw NotFoundException in dev you should get symfony debugger page and this error. In porduction this error is catch with ExceptionController and display blank error page (user should not see exceptions, only 500 error)

Comment: m sry for the mishap, actually I inserted `throw new createNotFoundException('The product does not exist');` just to check if the error message would show up in dev env. Forgot to remove it, but once I did the page works fine

Comment: How, ever www.blore.eduflats.com still shows 500 server error