# 500 Internal server error in development environment

Tags: symfony, apache2

I had to rephrase this question, as now I have better understanding of the problem. Here is the link for the previous one [Not able to display 404 error in prod environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746111/not-able-to-display-404-error-in-prod-environment/37747188#37747188).

I am working on a symfony2.8 application "myapp.com" , where in a client can register and have their own unique url "client1.myapp.com", so that their respective users can login and access the their homepage. I've created a demo client homepage with url "www.blore.myapp.com" the url works fine and the demo page gets loaded in both dev and prod environments. However when I click on any link which is supposed to display an error message eg. 404 not found, It works properly in the development environment, but in production environment it only display 500  internal server error. Here's the screenshot of it
[image]

I've tried removing the dev folder located inside the cache folder. Doesn't help much.
I am unable to understand if this is a symfony problem or apache2 configuration problem.
Any ideas?

Here is the production error log
[image]

Comment: Please check your error log and post the error as 500 error could be many things...

Comment: @LMS94 I've added the screenshot of the production error log

Comment: Can you add your routing file ? Or your route annotation ?

Comment: this is from `routing.yml` `subdomain_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     blore.eduflats.com|www.blore.eduflats.com
    defaults: { _controller: EduflatsBundle:Search:search }`

Comment: and this is the entire `routing_dev.yml`   `_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt`

`_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler`

`_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator`

`_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error`

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
`

Comment: So somewhere in your `error.html.twig` file, you're calling `path('homepage')` without the `domain` parameter. You either need to provide this parameter, or make it non required.

Comment: how can i make it non required? and in which file?

Comment: Also, consider updating your question with your routing files.  As you may have noticed, comments don't format well.